# Is It possible to have .NET 4.5 on application pools of IIS 7.5.1 on Server 2008 R2 Server Pack 1?

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-server-2008, .net-framework-version

I have an application running on Windows server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 with IIS version 7.5.1 and .NET framework V4.0. The TLS Connection is 1.0 and I wanted to upgrade the TLS connection to use 1.2. I have searched for so long and I found that it's related to the .Net Framework connection it has to be minimum 4.5. I downloaded .Net Framework 4.5 but I can't find it in the Application pools inside the IIS. Is there another possible way to upgrade to TLS 1.2 ? If upgrading the .Net framework is the solution, then how to apply .net framework version 4.5 to the IIS ?

Note, that I am using Microsoft VS 2010 and the solution is targeting .Net Framework V4.0 and I can't see the downloaded version 4.5 to choose as a target

Comment: The names shown in IIS Manager are missing. When you install .NET Framework 4.5 on a machine, then effectively .NET Framework 4.0 is replaced by it (in-place upgrade).

Answer (score 0):

> Framework connection it has to be minimum 4.5. I downloaded .Net Framework 4.5 but I can't find it in the Application pools inside the IIS. Is there another possible way to upgrade to TLS 1.2 ? If upgrading the .Net framework is the solution, then how to apply .net framework version 4.5 to the IIS ?

As Lex says that IIS management console will just show the CLR version which is always 4.0. If you want to check you have install the asp.net 4.5. I suggest you could try to open the regedit and locate the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full`.

Details ,you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed).

Besides, if you want to let your windows server 2008 to support tls1.2, you should also install the [windows update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi).

More details about how to enable TLS 1.2, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2).